# Include version number in a file on successful build

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, version

I developed an ASP.NET web site. When viewing the application in the browser the version number is shown in the footer of the application. But I want to communicate the version number with the customer even if the appliction is not running. 
Is it good to use a post build event for it to write it into a text file? If so, how can I access the version number (there is no predefined variable for this) and how can I write it into a text file via the command-line?
Are there any other, maybe simpler ways of getting this done?

Thanks for you help.

Edit: What I forgot to say is that it should be included when publishing the project using the Publish dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a build tool such as msbuild and nant to control the build number and update a application setting in the web.config.
or you can use some reflection code to retrieve it

```
Assembly web = Assembly.Load("App_Code");  
AssemblyName webName = web.GetName(); 
string myVersion = webName.Version.ToString();
```

preferably store the string in cache

Comment: Thanks I will look into MSBuild as it seems it is used automatically by Visual Studio. Perhaps editing the csproj files will do the trick.